# How can I create a method that takes a hash (with or without an assigned value) as an argument?

Tags: ruby, rspec

So I am working through test first and am a little stuck. Here is my code so far:

```
class Dictionary 
  attr_accessor :entries, :keywords, :item

  def initialize 
    @entries = {}
end

  def add(item)
    item.each do |words, definition| 
      @entries[words] = definition
    end
  end

  def keywords
    @entries.keys
  end

end#class
```

I am stuck at the rspec test right here:

```
it 'add keywords (without definition)' do
    @d.add('fish')
    @d.entries.should == {'fish' => nil}
    @d.keywords.should == ['fish']
  end
```

How can I switch my add method around to take either a key/value pair, or just a key with the value set to nil? The first test specifies that the hash is empty when it is created so I cant give it default values there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One might check the type of the parameter passed to the `add` method. Whether it’s not an [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html), which is apparently a mixin included in `Array`s, `Hash`es etc., just assign it’s value to `nil`:

```
def add(item)
  case item
  when Enumerable
    item.each do |words, definition| 
      @entries[words] = definition
    end
  else
    @entries[item] = nil
  end
end
```

Please note that `case` uses “[case equality](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D)” to check argument type.

Comment: It is a Dictionary class and the input will always be a string (or two if its a key/value)... and from what I just googled up, strings are not Enumerable as of 1.9 (sad face). I tried breaking up the parameter like this `def add((key,value))` using the extra parens to keep it to one arg, because two raises an argument error, and then setting the second one to nil - but then I got an error saying I can't use nil as a argument. I've actually tried a ton of things within the scope of a newb...Any ideas?

Comment: I stand corrected, because your code worked! I didn't initially understand your point that being a mixin in the #Array #Hash classes may make the string enumerable despite it no longer being Enumerable via the #string class alone. In my effort to learn I google the heck out of everything, sometimes it confuses me more lol. Thanks @mudasobwa!

Answer (score 2):

If you are always passing Strings to the method, you could just have a default value for the second string... Something like the following:

```
  def add(word, definition = nil)
      @entries[word] = definition
  end
```

So your code might look something like this:

```
class Dictionary 
  attr_accessor :entries, :keywords, :item

  def initialize 
    @entries = {}
  end

  def add(word, definition = nil)
      @entries[word] = definition
  end

  def keywords
    @entries.keys
  end

end#class
```

If you want multiple additions (i.e. `add key: "word", with: "many", options: nil`), that design might not work for you and you would need to create a solution that would work on the lines of what @mudasobwa suggested. Perhaps:

```
  def add(word, definition = nil)
      return @entries[word] = definition unless word.is_a?(Enumerable)
      return @entries.update word if word.is_a?(Hash)
      raise "What?!"
  end
```

**Update, as par request**

I updated the method above to allow for words that aren't strings (as you pointed out).

When passing a hash to a method, it is considered as a single parameter.

Key => Value pairs are an implied hash, so when passing a hash to a method, the following are generally the same:

```
Hash.new.update key: :value
Hash.new.update({key: :value})
```

Consider the following:

```
def test(a,b = nil)
  puts "a = #{a}"
  puts "b = #{b}"
end

test "string"
# => a = string
# => b = 
test "string", key: :value, key2: :value2
# => a = string
# => b = {:key=>:value, :key2=>:value2}
test key: :value, key2: :value2, "string"
# Wrong Ruby Syntax due to implied Hash, would raise exception:
# => SyntaxError: (irb):8: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>
test({key: :value, key2: :value2}, "string")
# correct syntax.
```

This is why, when you pass `add 'fish' => 'aquatic'`, it's considered only one parameter, a hash - as opposed to `add 'fish', 'aquatic'` which passes two parameters to the method.

If your method must accept different types of parameters (strings, hashes, numerals, symbols, arrays), you will need to deal with each option in a different way.

This is why @mudasobwa suggested checking the first parameter's type. His solution is pretty decent.

My version is a bit shorter to code, but it runs on the same idea.

```
  def add(word, definition = nil)
      return @entries[word] = definition unless word.is_a?(Enumerable)
      return @entries.update word if word.is_a?(Hash)
      raise "What?!"
  end
```

Comment: I actually tried that early on, but it gives me: ` {{"fish"=>"aquatic animal"}=>nil} (using ==)  ` where the nil ends up on the outside when a key/value pair is passed, and so it fails the spec for key/values. I think the problem is that is two arguments when I am only allowed one. I wish the solution could be so clean lol!! Thanks for your response!

Comment: Hi @HolyMoly , it seems you might have tried it without verifying your parameter was a String using the if statement. If you passed a hash to your method (i.e. `add 'fish' => 'aquatic'`), then your first parameter was a hash and the second one was your default `nil` object. Maybe you should have tested `add 'fish', 'aquatic'`.

Comment: P.S. Maybe try the last version I suggested. Seems it would cover more options for what you want.

Comment: I'm not sure if I am understanding you correctly, could you possibly update your answer to show me what you mean? Does your suggestion bring the argument passed down to one argument, not two (two won't pass rspec)? With that said, What if a parameter wasn't a string? What if it were an #Integer for example ':1 => 'odd integer' or something? wouldn't it be limiting to look for strings specifically? i'm pretty new so I still have a lot of confusion, lol...thanks!

Comment: After I thought about it some more, I think mudasowba suggested using Enumerable because it's like saying 'if there is more than one thing' ie: a key/value rather than just a key...but I could totally be wrong ;)